# Symfony2: How create simple form-filter for current (and all available) years

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.6

i'm trying to create a simple s2 form as a filter for a table with data.

Since I dont have an aproproate entity for that, i've made a simple model-class - `YearModel`

```
namespace MyBundle\Model\Filter;

class YearModel
{

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $years = array();

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getYears()
    {
        return $this->years;
    }

    /**
     * @param $year
     * @return YearModel
     */
    public function addYear( $year )
    {
        /** .... logic to add new year... */
    }

    /**
     * @param $year
     * @return YearModel
     */
    public function removeYear( $year )
    {
        /** .... logic to remove one ... */
    }
}
```

then a created an FormType for that particular filter:

```
namespace MyBundle\Form\Filter;

use /** sue statements */

class YearFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    const FILTER_TYPE_NAME = 'years_formfilter';


    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
      $builder->add('years', 'choice', array(
        'required'      => true,
        'placeholder'   => false,
      ));

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions( OptionsResolverInterface $resolver )
    {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
          'csrf_protection' => false,
          'data_class'      => "MyBundle\\Model\\Filter\\YearModel"
       ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
       return self::FILTER_TYPE_NAME;
    }
}
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
class MyController extends Controller 
{

  public function indexAction(Request $o_request)
  {

    // jsut for demo purpose
    $o_now = new \DateTime();
    // create a new instance of YearModel
    $o_filter_model = new MyBundle\Model\Filter\YearModel();
    // prepopulate with some mandatory data
    $o_filter_model->addYear( (int) $o_now->format('Y') );
    // create s2-form 
    $o_filter_form = $this->_createFilterForm( $o_filter_model );


    if( $o_request->getMethod == 'post' )
    {
      $o_filter_form->handleRequest( $o_request );
    }

    /** .... vodoo-magic ... */

    $a_twig_vars = array(
      'a_data_for_the_table' => $a_found_entries,
      'o_filter_form'        => $o_filter_form->createView(),
    );

    return $this->render("MyBundle:MyController:index.html.twig", $a_twig_vars)

  }

  private function _createFilterForm( MyBundle\Model\Filter\YearModel $o_filter_model)
  {
      $a_form_option = array(
      'method'          => 'POST',
      'attr'            => array(
          'novalidate'     => 'novalidate',
          'accept-charset' => 'UTF-8',
      ),
      );

      $o_filter_model = $this->createForm( new MyBundle\Form\Filter\YearFilterType(), $o_filter_model, $a_form_option );

      $o_filter_model->add('submit', 'submit', array(
      'label' => 'refresh',
      ));

      return $o_filter_model;
    }
}
```

as yuo can see - it's a pretty basic stuff, but **for some reasons the drop-down-list is ALWAYS EMPTY** even though `$o_filter_model->getYears()` returns an assoc array with years

WHAT DO I MISSING ?!

**UPDATE:**
Another think, i forgot to mention:

- the drop-down-list with years isn't realy static.
- current year
  should be always in the list
- other years (from DB) may be present

so that's way I always "add" current year within a controller! All other years will be read from DB (to achive this i tried to use `FormEvent::PRE_SET_DATA` Event)

```
/** in the formBuild-method ... */
cb_pre_set_data = function( FormEvent $o_event ) use ($em) {
   // get model-object
   // find all other years...
};

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $cb_pre_set_data);
```

Comment: Are you just wanting a choice field with a range of years?

Comment: @Qoop, yes, but the list ist not static. I know that I could add `choices => array('2013', '2014, '2015')` to a form-builder

Comment: You could add a range like `$range = range(date('Y') - 50, date('Y'))` and then  use that in your choices for the array keys and values like `'choices' => array_combine($range, $range)`. This would give you an array of years from 50 years ago to now.

Comment: @Qoop, thanks, but your suggestion makes "static" data and that's not what i'm looking for (take a look at the "update" section of my question for more details )

Comment: I don't think I actually understand your problem to be honest.